# Declaration of a VAR on Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning Node.js. On the book I am using there is a line that I am not sure I know exactly how it works and was looking for confirmation.

The line is:

`var user = req.user = users[req.params.name];`

I did some research on Google and the way I believe this works is:

As a first step will copy the content of users[request.params.name] into req.user then as a second step will copy the content of req.user into user. In the end user == users[req.params.name];

Can you please confirm that I am getting this right or, if not, explain how this line works?

thanks

Comment: You really couldn't figure this out just by running it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's *essentially* it. What you have there is a compound assignment. The result of an assignment expression is the value being assigned, and so that value can be the right-hand side of another assignment expression.

But there's actually something else that happens before any of that: The variable `user` gets defined in the current context. Here's a detailled order of operation:

1. Upon entry to the context, the variable `user` is defined with the value `undefined`. This happens before *any* step-by-step code in the context happens.
2. When the execution cursor reaches that code in the step-by-step execution of code, then:

   1. The property `params` is looked up on the variable `req`.
   2. The property `name` is looked up on the result of `req.params`.
   3. The property with the name defined by that value (the value of `req.params.name`) is retrieved from the object (presumably) referenced by the `users` variable.
   4. The resulting value is assigned to the `user` property on `req`.
   5. The same value is assigned to the `user` variable.

(I skipped a couple of bookkeeping steps to avoid overdoing the predantry.)

It's important to note that between steps 2.4 and 2.5 above, the value of `req.user` is *not* read from the `req.user` property. The value is determined in 2.3 and then used in 2.4 and again in 2.5. That is, `a = b = c;` is **not** the same as `b = c; a = b;`. The difference is that in the latter, the value is retrieved from `b` in the second assignment; in the former, it isn't, it's just reused from the `b = c` part. Now, when it's a simple property, that distinction doesn't particularly matter, but it does if you're using property accessor functions (either the non-standard kind from Mozilla's earlier variant of JavaScript, or the newly-standard kind from ECMAScript5). [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ATafayUZ/1) of the difference | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ATafayUZ/1/edit)

Comment: This is great and, honestly, much more than I was expecting. Appreciate your detailed response.